# Apache Shiro: Using isAuthenticated() || isRemembered() for an app without high security requirements

Tags: java, apache, security, authentication, shiro

As I understand it, Apache Shiro distinguishes two types of authentication:

`subject.isAuthenticated()` = the subject input credentials during this session

`subject.isRemembered()` = the subject is remembered from a previous session.

Due to the nature of these definitions, either one, or both, can be true.

For an app where security is not a top concern (i.e. I'm not worried about the chance that someone might do something while only being remembered from a past session, and not having authenticated), is it acceptable to just use `boolean auth = sub.isAuthenticated() || sub.isRemembered()` to check if a user is logged in? If not, what's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remembered != Authenticated - [This is key.](https://shiro.apache.org/java-authentication-guide.html#remembered-vs-authenticated)

For your application, don't check either one, just check for a permission or role instead, if in the future you don't want to allow remember me, you can just disable it via a configuration line.